# Function append in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I wonder why append add a number to every list that I have in my list. Not only to that one ([0]) that I have choosen. What's the difference between writing [0] or any other number next to append?

```
j = [[]] * 5 
j[0].append(5) # add 5 to every list on list
j[1].append(4) # what's the diffrence? [1] or [0]; it adds number to every element anyway
print (j)
j.append(0) # add 0 to the main list
print (j)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because your initial list `j` contains 5 references to the same object (so 5 copies to the same list). That's why everything you append goes to every list.

Instead, if you actually create 5 different sublists:

`j = [[] for _ in range(5)]`

Then it will work as you expect:

`[[5], [4], [], [], [], 0]`

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference.

`j = [[]] * 5`

Repeats the same empty list instance five times, once at each index.

IOW, the initial empty list is referenced 5 times.

You could verify this:

`id(j[0]) == id(j[1])`

To instantiate a different empty list at each index requires a comprehension:

`[[] for _ in range(5)]`